# Forcibly disconnect spammers

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, spam

I have Postfix, Dovecot and Amavis on my Ubuntu server. Recently, I get every 4 minutes a connection from IP 155.133.82.96, which appears to be Windows XP and maybe has a virus. Anyway, I found the way (after a lot of Googling) to make my Postfix not delay client access checks and I reject that IP. However, it stays around for a while.

I want to find a more radical way to forcibly disconnect the IP when the check has finished and the IP hasn't passed it. How can I do that? (I seek a Postfix solution, not iptables or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This address is part of a network served by a provider in Poland:
http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/155.133.82.96

I have also often scans against my MTA coming from that network, mostly/only for SASL login break attempts. What I recommend to keep that stuff away:

- A solution with Postfix only is not possible as far as I know. But you could use i. e. postgrey/cbpolicyd or a similar daemon or a table for the smtpd_client_restrictions, to handle blacklists. But that's some recurrently manual work …
- Better use fail2ban: apt-get install fail2ban
  http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
  It checks such intrusion attempts very well and bans the IP for 10 minutes (default) in the firewall. The basic rules should usually help enough to throttle such scans.
- Additionally you can log the activity of fail2ban into a database to count the number of bans of the IPs. Based on this data I block all intruders with more than 25 bans for 7 days. The firewall is updated hourly.
- Generally a veilling concept: If you're alone using this mail system, think about choosing a non-standard port in Postfix master.conf for your delivery:

```
smtp inet n  -  n - - smtpd **-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no**

smtps inet n  -  n - - smtpd **-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no**

**60666 inet n  -  n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes**
```

Usually SASL scans are against ports 25, 465, 567 and if there's no answer, they'll give up. Don't forget to allow additionally this non-standard port in your firewall rules. I'm using this concept for backup MXs with no client traffic.

fail2ban is a very good thing for securing many other services too like sshd or httpd, etc. and the setup is done in some minutes.

Comment: Someone from the mailing list also suggested using postscreen on Postfix, which also works for me.

Comment: Oh, interesting new Postfix feature:
[link](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html)
But think about that this works on the application layer only. With f2b you're able to prevent malware or malicious behaviour right before on the network layer.

Comment: Installed f2b successfully after a bit of fiddling with the configuration files.

Comment: Have a look to /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/defaults-debian.conf: 
'[postfix] 
enabled = true 
[dovecot] 
enabled = true' should be enough.